# Install XGBoost Multithreading Mac

Tags: r

So I have been following the instructions [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-osx) and I can't seem to figure out why XGBoost will not install correctly for R. I ran the appropriate command in the R Console only to still get:

`./dmlc-core/include/dmlc/omp.h:13:9: warning: Warning: OpenMP is not available, 
project will be compiled into single-thread code. Use OpenMP-enabled compiler to get benefit of multi-threading. [-W#pragma-messages]`

The command that I have been running in the R console is:

`install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("xgboost", repos="http://dmlc.ml/drat/", type = "source")`

Does anyone have updated instructions on how to download XGBoost? I have gcc 7 by the way.

Comment: Please state the "appropriate command" to clarify what you've tried. Besides, I don't know XGBoost, but the error message looks like you're missing some OpenMP development package. Have you tried to find and install one?

Comment: "install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("xgboost", repos="http://dmlc.ml/drat/", type = "source")
"

What are these openMP packages. I already have gcc without multilib

Comment: Fine. Could you please edit your question and insert it as a code block? Then  other readers will find it at the right place.

Comment: did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I only needed to use it for test a model I was given in R so I just skipped it and worked in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Install Homebrew.

Open a new terminal

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

Comment: The instructions say you need to clone the repository and then build it using make from the terminal. Did you do that?

Comment: Is that the part where you go make -j4? if so did that.